# Debugging WCF in VS2015 using SSL

Tags: wcf, ssl, visual-studio-2015

I have recently been asked to make changes to a wcf service which uses ssl. The developer who created the project no longer works for us. The problem I am having is that when I run it in visual studio 2015 I get an error pops up in a dialog box titled:

> "Failed to add service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata"

The error details are:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc'.    An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.    The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.HTTP GET Error    URI: https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc    There was an error downloading 'https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc'.    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.    The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

In the web.config file the service model is:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="NetiveApi.IisHost.TimesheetImport" behaviorConfiguration="metadatadiscov">
    <endpoint name="TimesheetWs" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding" contract="NetiveApi.IisHost.ITimesheetImport"/>
    <endpoint name="mexHttpsBinding" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  <service name="NetiveApi.IisHost.AssignmentImport" behaviorConfiguration="metadatadiscov">
    <endpoint name="AssignmentWs" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding" contract="NetiveApi.IisHost.IAssignmentImport"/>
    <endpoint name="mexHttpsBinding" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadatadiscov">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <!-- Use your own port numbers -->
          <!--<add scheme="http" port="8080" />-->
          <add scheme="https" port="444"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Service Contract for assignment

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IAssignmentImport
{
    [OperationContract]
    Acknowledgement ImportAssignment(string xml, string system, Guid authenticationToken);
}
```

Service Contract for timesheet

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface ITimesheetImport
{
    [OperationContract]
    Acknowledgement ImportTimesheet(string xml, string system, Guid authenticationToken);

    [OperationContract]
    string ApiActive();
}
```

I have read a number of articles about self signed certificates but they seem to suggest this is for use under IIS rather than IIS express in visual studio.

Any help and advice on this subject would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should check is whether you are able to browse the wsdl through https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svc.

I don't think you can because of missing  behavior configuration.

```
 <service name="NetiveApi.IisHost.TimesheetImport" behaviorConfiguration="metadatadiscov">
```

Now name your service behavior which has overridden the default implementation of the metadata.

```
 <behavior name="metadatadiscov" >
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <!-- Use your own port numbers -->
          <!--<add scheme="http" port="8080" />-->
          <add scheme="https" port="444"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
    </behavior>
```

Now you should be able to browse the wsdl. 
https://localhost:50257/AssignmentImport.svcIf not kindly post your service contract as well as Base address configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my post with the service contracts and more from the web.config including the recommended changes you specified. Sadly I'm still getting the same problem. I have also been unable to find any base address configuration. Is this required?